# How can I access memcached with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, memcached, ape

Let's say I have a working memcached deamon on a server.
Let's say that this server is able to handle server side Javascript ([APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) in my case).

It should be easy to access memcached with some Javascript right on the server (I mean, in my mind...).

But I've to admit I'm running out of idea...

"Help plz" ? :)

Thanks

EDIT :

This is working :

```
Ape.registerCmd("CMD", true, function(params, infos) {
Ape.log("cmd called");

var socket = new Ape.sockClient("11211", "127.0.0.1", {flushlf: true});

socket.onConnect = function() {
    Ape.log("Connected to Memcached");
    Ape.log("Issued 'stats' commande to Memcached...");
   this.write("stats\n");
    this.onRead = function(data) {
        Ape.log("Data from memcached : " + data);
    }
}
//data = ...
infos.sendResponse('return', {'data':data});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You talk to memcached over a socket, so if whatever server runs your JavaScript has a socket API you can write a memcached client for it.

If you can write javascript modules in C you can also do it, even if you don't have socket support in JavaScript.

Comment: I was digging that way... stay tuned :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there already exist memcache clients for JavaScript. You could try [jsmemcached](http://code.google.com/p/jsmemcached-client/) for example.

Comment: Saw it, but it relies on Jaxer... Not the lightest solution I was dreaming of.

Answer (score 0):

**silkjs** has a memcache mechanism built in it.

Here is the documentation: http://silkjs.org/documentation/Memcached